foreign movie about an a funny alien who damages crops after being drunk
I saw this movie when I was a child. This was some European movie with either english subtitles or dubbed in English (don't remember, the movie is easily 20+ years old or a bit more so.) 
The story goes like this (it is similar to ET but is not ET) . There is an alien whose spacecraft lands on some field late at night. The family whose land it is are poor. They have 2 or 3 children. The children befriend the alien and the alien does all sorts of pranks. In one of his pranks, he makes the crops better than ever before. The family then thinks to take part is a village competition hoping to beat the next door neighbors who are shown haughty and rude. The aliens job is to spread the alien manure or whatever he has which will make the crops big and healthy. What happens is the alien discovers chocolate or chocolate milk and that is his weakness. He becomes drunk on that chocolate milk and the resulting crops in the field are much larger (like in Jack the beanstalk) . I don't remember much of the remaining story but do remember it had a nice, warm ending. It seemed to be children's movie or made for children movie. Does anybody know the name of the movie ? 

Possibly Spaced Invaders from 1990:

When one saucer of an invasion force has engine trouble, it lands on Earth. It happens to be Halloween and it happens the invaders are only about 4 feet tall. As the bumbling aliens wander around the countryside they are taken to be children and they make friends with two children, one of whom is the daughter of the sheriff.

And in the end:

The alien manure rejuvenates the drought-stricken farmland and turns the regular green beans (for which the town is famous) into gigantic, 6 foot tall pods, enabling [farmer] Wrenchmuller to save the town from greedy real-estate developers.

It's American, though, and there's more than one alien. Here's the trailer:




+1 Very good movie, but I've seen this many times and I really don't think it fits the OP's description. I'll be surprised if it's what he is looking for.

I thought it seemed off too, but poor farmer -> manure -> giant beanstalks does fit. Maybe the OP got mixed up and the "drunk on chocolate" stuff is from another film?

While I have yet to see Spaced Invaders, I am quite positive it was an English film as the movie used subtitles or closed captions when I was watching it. I dunno whether it was drunk on chocolate but I do remember it was something which we would think of as pretty harmless and yet the alien gets high on it.
